# Drupal content type - populate Title field via Entity Reference

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm creating two custom **content types** for a Drupal 7 site - let's call them "Job Postings" and "Job Applications" since that illustrates the relationship between the two.

When a new Job Application is created, I want the Title to be the same as the Job Posting that it is for. The user will be getting to the new Job Application creation page via a link from a Job Posting display. I will pass the Job Posting node id to the Job Application   creation page in the URL, and grab it via Entity reference prepopulate into a hidden field.

What I'm *not* seeing is how to use Entity Reference to populate the Title of the new Job Application.

The Title has a field type of "Node Module Element" and it is required - and that doesn't seem modifiable. What I really *want* it to be is a field that pulls the Title from the associated Job Posting. I *don't* want the user to have to type the Title in freeform.

So actually, the question is twofold:

1. How do I pull in the job title from the Job Posting at all - I want to pass the node id of the Job Posting in the URL and then use *that* to look up the Title, I don't want to pass in the title itself (too much potential for abuse).
2. How do I specifically pull the Job Posting title in to the Title field of the new Job Application, which seems pretty impervious to being anything but what it is?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Entity Reference will help you to set the node title.

You should check out these modules.

- https://drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle
- https://drupal.org/project/auto_entitylabel

Comment: auto_entitylabel seems promising ... I've installed it to give it a try here. How do I tell which of the bazillions of tokens to use?  I would think [node:field-category:field-job-posting-nid:field_job_title] but that doesn't work?

Comment: Not sure which tokens to use as I don't know your setup.

But it should be the something like: the referenced fields node title.

Answer (score 0):

https://drupal.org/project/entityreference_autofill   The Entity reference autofill module gives Entity reference fields an option to populate other form fields with data from selected referenced entities.

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution is to use the title module in Drupal 7 to change the title field in into a fieldAPI which will then be recognised by the prepopulate module https://www.drupal.org/project/title